# Activity Indicator on "Send" button and "Save Draft" button on MFMailComposeViewController in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my iPad application, I am playing some PDF and Video files. In the application user have option to email these files to himself or a friend. Email functionality is working fine and email gets delivered too. However, when user presses send button to send the email it freezes the application for sometime, also, when user presses Save Draft button to save that email, it freezes too. I think this happens because of large size of the PDF or Video file being attached and since it takes time to attach a file. When app freezes it seems like as if the iPad has hung or the app is crashing. However, it is working fine. But it doesn't look good. That is why I need to apply an activity indicator when Send or Save Draft button is pressed. It should work till the file is attached. I would apply an activity indicator, but not sure how to apply it on Send and Save Draft buttons as they  come automatically in Email modal view controller.

Thanks in advance

PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also experienced the same problem. Not because of the size of an attachment. It happens arbitrarily, Here's a workaround:

- Enter anything in the "To:" field and then immediately backspace over it.
- The "Send" and "Cancel" buttons should start working again.
- If not, Quit Mail by double tapping the "Home" key, press and hold the "Mail" icon, when a minus signal shows press it on the "Mail" icon.
- Relaunch mail. Your previous work should be intact.

Hope this helps.